How do I prevent Nuxt from going to the Error layout when going to an invalid path?
I'm been looking through both GitHub issues, StackOverflow and the official documentation but I can't seem to find where and how to disable router from going to the error.vue page on going to an invalid path. I currently need to have a path to host my Wordpress website in and I need to disable the router from going to the error page on that specific path and it's pages. Is there anyway to achieve this?
I tried using middleware to clearError and ignore to ignore the path but it's not what I wanted.

"when going to an invalid path?" - can you clarify what is supposed to happen then? "I tried using middleware" - what did you try?

You can use pages/[...slug].vue (docs). If a page can't be found, [...slug].vue will be rendered instead of error.vue with 404 error.
BTW, the catch-all route only catches real 404, does not catch page validation failures. (example)
